# what does extra symbol and assembly code mean?

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, objdump

I have a simple c file:

```c
// filename: test.c
void fun() {}
```

Then I compile `test.c` to `libtest.so` using commands:

```sh
gcc -shared -fPIC -Wl,--gc-sections -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -o libtest.so test.c
strip -s ./libtest.so
```

Then use readelf to print symbols and its size:

```sh
readelf -sW ./libtest.so
```

I got:

```
Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 11 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
     1: 0000000000000420     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    9
     2: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __gmon_start__
     3: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND _Jv_RegisterClasses
     4: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.2.5 (2)
     5: 00000000002007c8     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  ABS _end
     6: 00000000002007b8     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  ABS _edata
     7: 00000000002007b8     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  ABS __bss_start
     8: 0000000000000420     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    9 _init
     9: 000000000000052a     6 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 fun
    10: 0000000000000568     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 _fini
```

Then use objdump to disassemble `.text` section of libtest.so:

```sh
objdump -S -d -j .text ./libtest.so
```

I got:

```
./libtest.so:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000460 <fun-0xca>:
 460:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
 464:   48 8b 05 15 03 20 00    mov    0x200315(%rip),%rax        # 200780 <_fini+0x200218>
 46b:   48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
 46e:   74 02                   je     472 <__cxa_finalize@plt+0x2a>
 470:   ff d0                   callq  *%rax
 472:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
 476:   c3                      retq
 477:   90                      nop
 478:   90                      nop
 479:   90                      nop
 47a:   90                      nop
 47b:   90                      nop
 47c:   90                      nop
 47d:   90                      nop
 47e:   90                      nop
 47f:   90                      nop
 480:   55                      push   %rbp
 481:   80 3d 30 03 20 00 00    cmpb   $0x0,0x200330(%rip)        # 2007b8 <__bss_start>
 488:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 48b:   41 54                   push   %r12
 48d:   53                      push   %rbx
 48e:   75 62                   jne    4f2 <__cxa_finalize@plt+0xaa>
 490:   48 83 3d f8 02 20 00    cmpq   $0x0,0x2002f8(%rip)        # 200790 <_fini+0x200228>
 497:   00
 498:   74 0c                   je     4a6 <__cxa_finalize@plt+0x5e>
 49a:   48 8d 3d 57 01 20 00    lea    0x200157(%rip),%rdi        # 2005f8 <_fini+0x200090>
 4a1:   e8 a2 ff ff ff          callq  448 <__cxa_finalize@plt>
 4a6:   48 8d 1d 3b 01 20 00    lea    0x20013b(%rip),%rbx        # 2005e8 <_fini+0x200080>
 4ad:   4c 8d 25 2c 01 20 00    lea    0x20012c(%rip),%r12        # 2005e0 <_fini+0x200078>
 4b4:   48 8b 05 05 03 20 00    mov    0x200305(%rip),%rax        # 2007c0 <__bss_start+0x8>
 4bb:   4c 29 e3                sub    %r12,%rbx
 4be:   48 c1 fb 03             sar    $0x3,%rbx
 4c2:   48 83 eb 01             sub    $0x1,%rbx
 4c6:   48 39 d8                cmp    %rbx,%rax
 4c9:   73 20                   jae    4eb <__cxa_finalize@plt+0xa3>
 4cb:   0f 1f 44 00 00          nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
 4d0:   48 83 c0 01             add    $0x1,%rax
 4d4:   48 89 05 e5 02 20 00    mov    %rax,0x2002e5(%rip)        # 2007c0 <__bss_start+0x8>
 4db:   41 ff 14 c4             callq  *(%r12,%rax,8)
 4df:   48 8b 05 da 02 20 00    mov    0x2002da(%rip),%rax        # 2007c0 <__bss_start+0x8>
 4e6:   48 39 d8                cmp    %rbx,%rax
 4e9:   72 e5                   jb     4d0 <__cxa_finalize@plt+0x88>
 4eb:   c6 05 c6 02 20 00 01    movb   $0x1,0x2002c6(%rip)        # 2007b8 <__bss_start>
 4f2:   5b                      pop    %rbx
 4f3:   41 5c                   pop    %r12
 4f5:   c9                      leaveq
 4f6:   c3                      retq
 4f7:   66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00    nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
 4fe:   00 00
 500:   48 83 3d e8 00 20 00    cmpq   $0x0,0x2000e8(%rip)        # 2005f0 <_fini+0x200088>
 507:   00
 508:   55                      push   %rbp
 509:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 50c:   74 1a                   je     528 <__cxa_finalize@plt+0xe0>
 50e:   48 8b 05 73 02 20 00    mov    0x200273(%rip),%rax        # 200788 <_fini+0x200220>
 515:   48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
 518:   74 0e                   je     528 <__cxa_finalize@plt+0xe0>
 51a:   48 8d 3d cf 00 20 00    lea    0x2000cf(%rip),%rdi        # 2005f0 <_fini+0x200088>
 521:   c9                      leaveq
 522:   ff e0                   jmpq   *%rax
 524:   0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)
 528:   c9                      leaveq
 529:   c3                      retq

000000000000052a <fun>:
 52a:   55                      push   %rbp
 52b:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 52e:   c9                      leaveq
 52f:   c3                      retq
 530:   55                      push   %rbp
 531:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 534:   53                      push   %rbx
 535:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
 539:   48 8b 05 90 00 20 00    mov    0x200090(%rip),%rax        # 2005d0 <_fini+0x200068>
 540:   48 83 f8 ff             cmp    $0xffffffffffffffff,%rax
 544:   74 19                   je     55f <fun+0x35>
 546:   48 8d 1d 83 00 20 00    lea    0x200083(%rip),%rbx        # 2005d0 <_fini+0x200068>
 54d:   0f 1f 00                nopl   (%rax)
 550:   48 83 eb 08             sub    $0x8,%rbx
 554:   ff d0                   callq  *%rax
 556:   48 8b 03                mov    (%rbx),%rax
 559:   48 83 f8 ff             cmp    $0xffffffffffffffff,%rax
 55d:   75 f1                   jne    550 <fun+0x26>
 55f:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
 563:   5b                      pop    %rbx
 564:   c9                      leaveq
 565:   c3                      retq
```

We can tell that the size of symbol `fun` is 6 which is correspond to virtual address 0x52a ~ 0x52f.

I have two question:

1. what does symbol `fun-0xca` do?
2. what does assembly code from 0x530 to 0x565 in symbol `fun` do?

Comment: Looks like C++ name mangling, especially given the lack of a `fun` symbol.  Are you *sure* you used `gcc` not `g++`?  On my Arch Linux desktop, I get a `fun` symbol with the `gcc` command you showed.

Comment: @PeterCordes I thought g++ is the same with gcc. I was wrong. I compile test.c using gcc, and I have update the post above.

Comment: @expoter What you should really avoid is writing `gcc` in your instructions but then secretly use `g++`.   Always make sure your [mcve] is correct!

Comment: If you want to know what that other code does, don't `strip` the library before disassembling it!  There might still be symbols on each of those other functions.

Comment: the gnu disassembler will take the labels it has and through some algorithm use those, fun-0xCA just means I see a label named fun at 0x0052a and this is fun-0xca, 0x0460 same goes for the <__cxa_finalize@plt+0xaa>

Comment: the code in question is not related to the function you provided it is additional stuff which as pointed it we cant tell because the info was stripped out.  What is the exercise here if you want to know what the compiler produces for fun() then compile to a object and disassemble that dont link it (just yet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omit the `strip -s ./libtest.so`.

In the GCC-created `libtest.so`, each separate function has a symbol in the symbol table.  `objdump -drwC -Mintel libtest.so` will show names for each one, like `_init`, `deregister_tm_clones`, `register_tm_clones`, and `__do_global_dtors_aux`.  These come from CRT startup code, I think; use `gcc -v` when you're linking to see any extra `.o` files it passes to `ld`.

**Stripping symbols removes that information, leaving machine code in the text section without a symbol name**.  The only symbol left for `objdump` to reference is `fun`, so it labels the first block of code relative to that, as `fun-0xca`.